# How to use CopyWebpackPlugin in nuxt.config.js?

Tags: nuxt.js

I trying to use this and it doesn't work:

```
build: {
   extend: (config) => {
            config.plugins.push(
                new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                  {
                    from: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/EXAMPLEPACKAGE/static'),
                    to: path.join(__dirname, 'static/example/')
                  }
                ])
            );

    },
},
```

I also tried like this

```
build: {
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                  {
                    from: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/EXAMPLEPACKAGE/static'),
                    to: path.join(__dirname, 'static/example/')
                  }
        ])
    ]
}
```

How to use CopyWebpackPlugin in nuxt.config.js?

Comment: I have the same problem? Did you solved it?